# azureStorageUri not created when create mobileAppContentFile in Microsoft Intune

Tags: azure-storage, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I want to create a [mobileAppContentFile](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_apps_mobileappcontentfile_create). For this I make a POST request to:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/0122f94e-45c4-458a-a25a-c08135a036fc/microsoft.graph.windowsMobileMSI/contentVersions/1/files`

with this request body:

```json
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppContentFile",
    "azureStorageUri": "https://NAME.blob.core.windows.net/intune/TestApp.msi",
    "name": "TestApp.msi",
    "isCommitted": false,
    "uploadState": "azureStorageUriRequestPending"
}
```

I receive `201 Created` response but `azureStorageUri` is `null`:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#deviceAppManagement/mobileApps('0122f94e-45c4-458a-a25a-c08135a036fc')/microsoft.graph.windowsMobileMSI/contentVersions('1')/files/$entity",
    "azureStorageUri": null,
    "azureStorageUriExpirationDateTime": null,
    "createdDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "id": "ca57173c-5f67-4048-90bf-3bac136de964",
    "isCommitted": false,
    "manifest": "bWFuaWZlc3Q=",
    "name": "TestApp.msi",
    "size": 0,
    "sizeEncrypted": 0,
    "uploadState": "azureStorageUriRequestPending"
}
```

What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: It looks like your passing a URI to a directory `https://NAME.blob.core.windows.net/intune/` rather than to the actual file `https://NAME.blob.core.windows.net/intune/TestApp.msi`.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur you mean that I need to set the "azureStorageUri": `https://NAME.blob.core.windows.net/intune/TestApp.msi` in the body of the request or PUT file to `https://NAME.blob.core.windows.net/intune/TestApp.msi`?

Comment: My understanding is that you need to first upload the file to Azure Storage and then provide the API with the URL to that file.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I did so, uploaded the file to Azure Storage and then provide the API with the URL to that file. I changed the description, you can see

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt,as @Marc Lafleur said, you need to upload the file to Azure sotrage first and then provide the required Property value of them. 
Second,In your request body, you didn't fill with full required properties.

Follow this example to create one mobile app content file :

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/{mobileAppId}/contentVersions/{mobileAppContentId}/files
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 342

{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppContentFile",
  "azureStorageUri": "Azure Storage Uri value",
  "isCommitted": true,
  "name": "Name value",
  "size": 4,
  "sizeEncrypted": 13,
  "azureStorageUriExpirationDateTime": "2017-01-01T00:00:08.4940464-08:00",
  "manifest": "bWFuaWZlc3Q=",
  "uploadState": "transientError"
}
```

Comment: I did everything as you described I receive 201 Created response but azureStorageUri is null.

Comment: I have a suspicion that the case is in the directory of my MS account. My account has two catalogs "A" and "B". In the catalog "A" I have registered an application in Azure AD and Intune himself. In the directory "A" I create a mobile application, content and content file through the Graph API, but I do not have access to the Storage. I have access to the Storage in the "B" directory and the file is downloaded using the "B" directory.

Comment: It is possible that due to the fact that there is no file in the directory "A" in the Storage (and the file itself in the Storage  "B" directory), I do  have the azureStorageUri is null.?